# Meaning of “how do you close?” in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Source Comedy Bang Bang Podcast, Episode 1 Thomas Lennon Rob Heubel, 18.52 - 19.10

> A: This is the scenario, you bring a girl back to your place, no  furniture, just an inflatable bed. **How do you close?**
>
> B: How do you not close when the only thing there is a bed

I wonder if it means “how do you get her into having sex with you.” Is that wrong? Thank you.

Comment: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/close-the-deal

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrong. '[Close here means 'close the deal'](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/always-be-closing.asp)'  (from salesman terminology), and figuratively extended to mean get what you want or were planning for. In this case from context (and [common slang usage](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/close-the-deal)) that is definitely sex.

Comment: Source? Or this may not be answer I'm afraid. Close enough, though!